# Get data from two different database columns

Tags: laravel, search, sum

i have tow column in my sql and use this query to search

```
$Person->where('name','LIKE',"%{$keyword}%")
                    ->orWhere('family_Name','LIKE',"%{$keyword}%")
                    ->orWhere('id',$keyword);
```

but if user type name and family name together then result is null
how can i get where from sum of tow column? or any other way

Comment: You really should consider using Laravel Scout; https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/scout.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, a raw sql command like the one below might work for you.

$person->where(DB::raw('CONCAT_WS(" ", name, family_Name)'), 'like', '%'.$keyword.'%')->get();

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want search "John Doe". You put "John" at column `name` and "Doe" at `family_name`.

So, you can add `CONCAT_WS()` for this.

```php
$Person
   ->where('name','LIKE',"%{$keyword}%")
   ->orWhere('family_Name','LIKE',"%{$keyword}%")
   ->where(DB::raw('CONCAT_WS(" ", name, family_name)'), 'like', "%{$keyword}%") // <-- here
   ->orWhere('id',$keyword);
```